# Fragment и метод

Tags: java, android-fragment, методы

Почему не работает Метод vMoney();
В методе onViewCreate,
Хотя в обработке нажатия,все нормально и все работает?

```
public class FragmentJob extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    Money mon = new Money();
    public TextView money_job;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         vMoney();
         setRetainInstance(true);
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job, container, false);


        Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Job1);
        Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Job2);
        Button button3 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Job3);
        Button button4 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Job4);
        Button button5 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Job5);
        Button button6 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Job6);
        Button button7 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Job7);
        Button button8 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Job8);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
        button5.setOnClickListener(this);
        button6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        button8.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Job1:
                mon.salary1();
                vMoney();
                break;
            case R.id.Job2:
                mon.salary2();
                vMoney();
                break;
            case R.id.Job3:
                mon.salary3();
                vMoney();
                break;
            case R.id.Job4:
                mon.salary4();
                vMoney();
                break;
            case R.id.Job5:
                mon.salary5();
                vMoney();
                break;
            case R.id.Job6:
                mon.salary6();
                vMoney();
                break;
            case R.id.Job7:
                mon.salary7();
                vMoney();
                break;
            case R.id.Job8:
                mon.salary8();
                vMoney();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void vMoney(){
        int j = money;
        money_job = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.money_job);
        money_job.setText(String.valueOf(j));}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что уместнее будет вызвать данный метод ( `vMoney` ) при старте фрагмента, в методе `onStart()`.

При построении фрагмента у Вас может и не быть ресурсов, к которым Вы обращаетесь.

По этой же причине всё работает при обработке нажатия(активити и фрагмент уже построены и стартовали и Вам доступны все объекты, к которым Вы обращаетесь.)

Изучите внимательнее жизненный цикл активити и фрагментов.

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-lifecycle.php

Comment: Прочитал,знания почерпнул,исправил,Спасибо ДЖАВА и Андроид это круто,а вам благодарочка!

Answer (score 0):

```js
   @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        vMoney();
    }
```